# How many bytes does a string take up in x64?

Tags: c#, string, memory, clr

For the purpose of learning, I'm trying to understand how C# strings are internally stored in memory.

According to this [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/), C# string size is (x64 with .NET framework 4.0) :

```
26 + 2 * length
```

A string with a single character will take `(26 + 2 * 1) / 8 * 8 = 32 bytes` .
This is indeed similar to what I measured.

What puzzle me is what is in that 26 bytes overhead.

I have run the following code and inspected memory :

```
string abc = "abcdeg";
string aaa = "x";
string ccc = "zzzzz";
```

[image]

AFAIK those blocks are the following :

- Green : Sync block (8 bytes)
- Cyan : Type info (8 bytes)
- Yellow : Length (4 bytes)
- Pink : The actual characters : 2 bytes per char + 2 bytes for NULL terminator.

Look at the "x" string. It is indeed 32 bytes (as calculated).

Anyway it looks like the end of the string if padded with zeroes.
The "x" string could end up after the two bytes for NULL terminator and still be memory aligned (thus being 24 bytes).
Why do we need an extra 8 bytes ?

I have experimented similar results with other (bigger) string sizes. 
It looks like there is always an extra 8 bytes.

Comment: As you know, the C#(CLR) using reflections. I don't know packing of memory exactly but it might be related with the reflection(RTTI).

Comment: Before CLR v4, the String type used to have an extra field.  You see m_stringLength, there used to also be an m_arrayLength.  It was dropped, but they did not also make the allocation 4 bytes shorter.  The exact reason for that is mysterious, but I bet it was because that would make a lot of existing pinvoke code now get to corrupt the heap.  Passing a string instead of a StringBuilder, required when the native code mutates the string, is a very common mistake.

Comment: Could that m_arrayLength be 8 bytes in x64 ? I found out that the internal field which store array length is indeed 8 bytes in x64. That would explain the extra 8 byte chunk at the end each string.

Comment: No, it was declared Int32, 4 bytes long.  There is no 'internal field' nor 8 extra bytes, just 4.  0 bytes (beyond the zero-terminator and those 4 extra ones) are generated to make the entire object a multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: Tests seems to confirm what you say : 8 bytes alignment seems to be done after 4 extra bytes have been added (along with 2 bytes for null terminator). so 6 bytes in total. Strangely, this only apply for x64. In x32 there is no extra 4 bytes added (only 2 bytes terminator then 4 bytes alignement is done)

Comment: Oh, wait, these objects don't live on the heap at all.  They are interned strings because you used a literal in the code.  I never did find the interning code in the CLR yet.  Consider trying it with a string expression instead of a literal to get more truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant suggested, there is an extra field added at the end of string object which is 4 bytes (in x64, it might require another 4 bytes extra, for padding).

So in the end we have :

```
= 8 (sync) + 8 (type) + 4 (length) + 4(extra field) + 2 (null terminator) + 2 * length 
= 26 + 2 * length
```

So Jon Skeet's blog post was right (how could it be wrong ?)